# How to get fluffy material like this - do I need hair particles or just material?

Tags: texturing, materials, particles, hair

Alright, this is a Blender x Substance question but all ties back to Blender materials. Ive been trying to nail something like this (NOTICE the little stray fluffy hairs on the surface of the cloth material.

[image: e]

Ideally I'd like to achieve this with material alone, and I know this material was made in Substance. I've looked everywhere and can't find a great cloth material for Substance or Blender that has these fuzzy hairs, and actually looks realistic.

How can I do this? Do I need to incorporate a hair particle system?

Comment: Hello :). Simon Thommes made a great [procedural knitwear shader](https://simon-thommes.com/knittr-procedural-knitwear-shader-blender). It uses microdisplacement for that fluffy look.

Comment: The closest result I managed to find was this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8NT5Bth450&t=301s